# Android IMMERSIVE mode not working

Tags: android

I make Android 5.x  APP

I want `IMMERSIVE mode  = fullscreen`

So...

`MainActivity`  `setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener`  call with success

but

`Sub Activity` move  `setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener`   call   not working

help me..

=================

MainActivity.java

onCreate

UiChangeListener();

```
public  void UiChangeListener()
{   
    decorView = getWindow().getDecorView(); 

       decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {   
           if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {  
               decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                       View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
           }
       }
   });
```

}

SubActivity.java

onCreate

UiChangeListener();

```
public  void UiChangeListener()
{   
    decorView = getWindow().getDecorView(); 

       decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {   
           if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {  
               decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                       View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
           }
       }
   });
```

}

subactivity
uichangeListener()  not working

Comment: please give ur sample code.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the documentation https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html#sticky you should call immersive initialization like this:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

Override onWindowFocusChanged in you SubActivity.